# Consumer Constructor Pitfalls

Tags: java, constructor, java-8

Look at the following code:

```
class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

    Person(Consumer<Person> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm using "consumer constructor", so I can create a person like this:

```
var person = new Person(p -> {
    p.name = "John";
    p.age = 30;
})
```

Seems like this approach is much better than builder pattern or all-arguments constructor.

4 years have passed since Java 8 was released but nobody uses consumer constructors (at least I haven't seen it before).

I do not understand why? Is this approach has some pitfalls or limitations?

I have found one, but I don't think it is critical:

```
class AdvancedPerson extends Person {

    String surname;

    AdvancedPerson(Consumer<AdvancedPerson> consumer) {
        super(); // <-- what to pass?
        consumer.accept(this);
    }

}
```

Sure we can create a no-arguments constructor in `Person` and just call it in `AdvancedPerson` consumer constructor. But is this a solution?

So what do you think about it?
Is it safe to use consumer constructors?
Is this a substitute for builders and all-argument constructors? Why?

Comment: How about a no-argument constructor that's protected, perhaps in combination with just having `AdvancedPerson` use the `Consumer<Person>`?

Comment: Did you mean "no-argument constructor that's private"? Because we can call protected constructors in children. Otherwise, could you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, I mean protected.  As in it prevents the `Person` class from having to expose a no-argument constructor.

Comment: I've pasted your code to the IDE (NetBeans beta), and the warning for the line `consumer.accept(this);` is *Leaking this in constructor*. Hmm...

Comment: @zlakad, interesting and useful tip. does Netbeans do this analysis by default or have you installed some plugins?

Comment: @Andrew no, no plugins...

Comment: @Andrew, I mean consumer constructors, not Java 8.

Comment: @zlakad, Well, IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 didn't show me the warning. Perhaps it is disabled by default.

Comment: @Feeco, here is the link for my NetBeans:
http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Comment: The accepted answer names all the disadvantages. But even without knowing all the disadvantages, what was the supposed advantage over, e.g. `var person = Person.builder().name("John").age(30).build();`? I don’t see any.

Comment: @Holger , I'm happy to change the accepted answer if you could clarify your point of view. Now I agree with all 4 points of the accepted answer, especially with the first. I also agree with "instance leak" from the other answers.

Comment: I think the accepted answer is fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's neither safe nor elegant from my point of view. There are several reasons against this approach: The worst thing about it is that it not only allows but also forces you to let the this reference escape while the object is not initialized yet. This has several severely bad implications:

- The consumer will have a reference to an object who is in a mid constructor call. The consumer can then do all kind of evil things like e.g. call methods overridden by another child class.
- Also the consumer may be able to see the object in a partial state, e.g. some member initialized while other aren't. This can get even worse when multi-threading is involved.
- Immutable objects are impossible to create with this approach as you have to allow the consumer to meddle with the internals of the object under construction.
- Last but not least you put the burden of being responsible for guaranteeing for the class' invariants to the consumer. This is definitely something a class should be responsible for itself.

See the second chapter of effective java for best practices concerning creating objects.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like I don't control the process of initialisation at all.

I don't know how many fields have been set, what their values are. I don't know which methods (and how many) a consumer has called. It looks like I break the encapsulation rules.

I also expose the `this` reference for the outer world.
The caller may do with `this` whatever they want. And I won't be notified about that. Multithreading has a term called 'improper publication'. I would use it here.

Answer (score 4):

Consumer constructors appear to present a concise way in Java to write code that in other languages would be referred to as "properties".  Just pass in a `Consumer` that initializes the state of the object.

But this cannot work with proper class design, which includes encapsulation.  Here, this means that `name` and `age` should be `private`.  This means that the `Consumer` no longer has access to the instance variables and no longer compiles.

Encapsulation and the Builder Pattern both have the advantage that invalid states of the objects are checked and rejected.

If Java had the concept of properties, where code such as `obj.prop1 = value;` and `variable = obj.prop2;` in reality called methods, then this would not be a concern.  But it doesn't have this concept.

The pitfall you have found could be worked around by passing a `Consumer` for each superclass as well as the class in question, e.g.:

```
AdvancedPerson(Consumer<Person> pConsumer, Consumer<AdvancedPerson> consumer) 
{
    super(pConsumer); // <-- what to pass?
    consumer.accept(this);
}
```

However, that means that a user must pass in a different `Consumer` for every superclass, which doesn't make much sense.

In addition, passing `this` from a constructor is not a good idea; this is an *instance leak*, where outside code can access an object that isn't fully constructed yet.

Encapsulation, `this` leaking, and the complication of multiple `Consumer`s in a class hierarchy are all good reasons *not* to use consumer constructors.

Comment: you don't need a `Consumer<Person>` for `AdvancedPerson`. `Consumer<AdvancedPerson>` is able to set all the `Person` fields as well as the `AdvancedPerson` fields :)

Comment: @Andrew The only possible way that could work well with encapsulation is with `protected` fields in all classes.  Then what about implementation details?  A (contrived) example here would be a `fullName` variable, which should be derivable from the other values.  This passes the responsibility of implementation to outside code.  While the "what to pass to super" problem may be minor, it doesn't take away from the problems of encapsulation and `this` leaking.